# Swift плавное появление текста в label

Tags: swift

имеется допустим один лейбел и кнопка, по нажатию на кнопку текст в лейбле меняется. Можно ли как то сделать так, что бы текст во первых плавно появлялся, т.е. сначала прозрачный а потом уже нормальный и можно ли сделать появление текста так, что бы это выглядело как будто его набирают, т.е. буквы будут появляться поочередно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем расширение для `UILabel` (посимвольное отображение):

```
extension UILabel {
    func animate(newText: String, characterDelay: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.text = ""
            for (index, character) in newText.characters.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + characterDelay * Double(index)) {
                    self.text?.append(character)
                    self.fadeTransition(characterDelay) // это анимация проявления
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Добавляем расширение для `UIView` (анимация проявления):

```
extension UIView {
    func fadeTransition(_ duration:CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation = CATransition()
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        animation.type = kCATransitionFade
        animation.duration = duration
        layer.add(animation, forKey: kCATransitionFade)
    }
}
```

Вызываем так:

```
label.animate(newText: "Hello Animation", characterDelay: 0.5)
```

Comment: Работает) задержку лучше всего на 0,05 ставить, а то выглядит не очень красиво когда медленнее))
и еще он на character ругается, это нормально?)