# swift анимация UIImageView плавное появление картинки

Tags: swift

немного с анимациями поработал, но вот не знаю, как сделать так, что бы например картинка на фоне появлялась сначала прозрачной потом виднелась чуть и так постепенно появилась?

Comment: Вы можете использовать расширение для UIView из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848443/swift-плавное-появление-текста-в-label например imageView.fadeTransition(0.5)

Comment: да вот пробовал, расширение есть изменил его под  UIImageView. ПОтом вызываю функцию при загрузке экрана и ноль эмоций

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Анимация исчезания изображения.
Проявление делается также, только `alpha = 1`, перед тем как отобразить скройте изображение `alpha = 0`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
self.imageVIew.alpha = 0.0   
}) { _ in print("Animation Done") }
```

Comment: идеально) спасибо